# What methods of input / output are legal for C++ compile-time golfing

Tags: discussion

I recently played around with C++11 compile-time golfing:
[Tournament Format Synonyms](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54768/tournament-format-synonyms/54804#54804)

That is, its a C++ program which runs via templates and computes the answer during compile-time, such that it's possible to check the output via static asserts.

A similar thing can be done now with constexpr functions, or some hybrid.

One thing which I realized that I should probably have looked up first was how I should do standard input and output for it to be "legit".

It's extremely awkward to do any kind of string manipulation at all in templates, because templates basically cannot manipulate a const char * like you do in C. In C++11 there are variadic templates and that is what I used. Basically in my program I define a struct:

```cpp
template<char...> struct S{};
```

so this type can bind to an arbitrary sequence of chars.

Then I define my "main" function to be a metafunction which also takes a char... and returns an S. So it's some template like

```cpp
template<char...> struct F{ typedef ... t; }
```

In my examples I show that you can check the output like:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same<typename F<'B','o','3'>::t, S<'F','t','2'>>::value, "fail");
```

So here I think are some reasonable questions:

1. If the template S is solely used as an output mechanism, then why do I have to pay to define it? IMO This would be like if std::cout and fprintf didn't exist in C and you had to implement them in code golf solutions if you wanted to use them.
2. At the same time, it turned out to be pretty useful for me that I could control what S was. For instance in my final solution I changed it to a sequence of "wchar_t" (unicode characters), this allowed me to use a single integral type instead of a mix of ints and chars and simplify my templates and save a lot of space. Is that legit? Should I also be allowed to do that "for free"?
3. In this example it wasn't too bad, but if variadic templates like S are the only legal way to get string input in template metaprograms, it's inherently limiting because you can basically only access the front of a template parameter pack. If you allow the input / output to be represented as an mpl vector then it's a lot more capable right out of the box. Is that legit? Some different options for compile time string processing are discussed here, especially the one in the top answer is quite convenient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858141/conveniently-declaring-compile-time-strings-in-c But if declaring that thing counts against your code golf its no use.

IMO, C++ is already a pretty bad code golf language, and the meta programming language is, by comparison, notoriously verbose and with a strange mix of power and severe limitations. So it seems reasonable to just be very liberal with what input / output methods are permitted.

The thing though is that if the user is defining the template that signifies a string its a bit strange because then I guess you want to validate that also externally. In my examples for instance, all these checks based on std::is_same would pass if both F and S were just always typedef'd to "void". But you would kind of have to ungolf my program to see that that isn't what's happening.

Comment: I'm no expert on TMP, but I think the answer to this boils down to: *Do we consider it a separate language?* C++ already has ways to get input/output that are standardized. If TMP is just a *technique* (as I might claim), then you're just purposefully choosing code that looks inherently bad at golf (and ignoring language features that would lower your score). I could choose bad golfing techniques in other languages, but I shouldn't expect basic IO and scoring to change when I do.

Comment: Geobits: the thing is that I can't actually use standard input and output functions at *compile-time*

Comment: My point is that (if I understand correctly) that's not the fault of the language you're using, but the *code* you're using.

Comment: no, i think its intrinsic to doing TMP. template expressions get fully evaluated while the compiler is running, before the executable even exists. you can't like, then get std::in from int main and pass it to a template, because the template is already set in stone. you have to pass the template information via the type system

Comment: it depends on your point of view but some people basically say that "pure" C++ tmp is a completely different language which is pure functional in nature, based on exploiting template partial specialization, dependent typing, inheritance and function overload resolution to create control flow and what kind of "state" there is.

Comment: Like I said, that's what I think it boils down to. I'm of the opinion that it's just C++, but I haven't made it an answer because I'm not *that* well versed in it.

Comment: if my code fundamentally looks like `template<typename INPUT> struct { typedef (...) OUTPUT; };` there's no way that i can connect that to std::in. changing the input requires recompiling the program. in http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods this thread people say that "functions may take their input as an argument" and "functions may output via their return value" what i want is that C++ metafunctions also be treated as functions here, which is only fair to TMP. but some details aren't clear esp. what is the "native" string type

Comment: 1 yes you should. 2 No. 3 It's not legit. `If std::cout and fprintf didn't exist in C, you had to implement them in code golf solutions` and you should pay for this or chose another language